# Set httppostedfilebase if validation fails in ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

Here is my problem. I've already implemented uploading and downloading of images in my application. Where I'm having issues is with posting back to the server when there are validation errors. When this happens the controller redirects back to the page and displays all errors, but the HttpPostedFileBase object is empty! So I have to display a "no image" picture and force the user to re-upload an image. What I want, is for the image to be loaded back into HttpPostedFileBase so that it can be used again without having to upload anything twice! All the other text values get redisplayed on the page, why can't the image do the same?
Is this possible with code behind or do I have to do some javascript/ajax type stuff? Kinda a newbie to javascript/ajax so any help will be appreciated.

Here is my controller. If validation fails I redisplay the view and show the errors and I tried setting the HttpPostedFileBase back to the HttpPostedFileWrapper that gets returned but it doesn't work when I post back a second time, the object is empty. So if I resubmit the form the image is still empty.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStudentViewModel studentViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do stuff here
        } else
        {
            var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse();
            studentViewModel.Years = years.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.ToString(),
                Value = c.ToString(),
                Selected = (c == studentViewModel.SelectedYearId)
            });
            studentViewModel.StudentImageResult =
                new FileContentResult(
                    System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
                        System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/no_image.jpg"))),
                    "image/jpeg");
            // I thought I could reset the httppostedfilewrapper here but it doesn't work
            studentViewModel.HttpPostedFileBase= studentViewModel.StudentImageFileBase;
            return View(studentViewModel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. 
Because you cannot set the value of a file-upload in HTML or with JavaScript. 
If you could, that would be a severe security flaw, because you theoretically could maliciously upload an entire hard-drive.

You can however do the validation in JavaScript before sending. 
Then you don't need a Post-Back, which is far user-friendlier anyway.

Otherwise, you can save the file if validation fails, and display the name in a label, and have the id/uid of the image in a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

If the validation fails, why not store the file locally on the server in a temporary location and show the image back using

```
@Html.Image("Name", Url.Content("~/Images/TempLocation/temp.jpg"), "Picture")
```

On re-post, if model is valid, you can save the "temp.jpg" from the temporary location into your application.